# FORALL causes stack overflow

Tags: fortran

I am implementing a genetic algorithm to numerically estimate some coefficients in a system of ODEs based on experimental data. I am just learning Fortran along as I implement the algorithms. My config is a Intel Fortran 2015 running on Windows 7/Visual Studio 2013, on an old i7 processor.

I have the following piece among a multitude of lines of code:

```
DO i = 1, N_CROMOSOMES
    IF (population(9,i) < 0.0_DOUBLE) population(9, i) = square_error(population(1:8, i))
END DO
```

Where I just defined DOUBLE to be:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DOUBLE = 16
```

N_CROMOSOMES is an INTEGER argument to the function, that defines the size of the array population, which in turn is a (9 x N_CROMOSOMES) array of type REAL(KIND=DOUBLE). For each column on this array, its first 8 elements represent the 8 coefficients that I am estimating, and the ninth element is the error associated with that particular 8 guesses for the coefficients. square_error is the function that determines it.

In this point of the program, I have marked columns that were just created or that were altered as having an error of -1. Hence, the "IF (population(9,i)<0.0_DOUBLE)": I am checking the columns of the array whose error is -1 in order to compute their error.

The thing is, I just rewrote most of my code, and spent the past few days correcting mysterious bugs. Before this, the code worked just fine with a FORALL instead of DO. Now it says gives an error "stack overflow" when I use FORALL, but works with DO. But it takes a lot more time to do its job.

Does anyone knows the cause of this, and also, how to solve it? It is clear to me that my code can highly benefit from paralellization, but I am not so sure how to do it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is a typical value for `N_CROMOSOMES`?  And should that have an "H" in it?

Comment: you might want to show the code for `square_error`.  BTW you are free to define "double" as you like but its liable to lead to confusion if you also have legacy code that uses `double precision` which is probably equivalent to `kind=8`

Comment: If `forall` triggers a stack overflow I suspect the creation of large temporary arrays though I don't quite see how rewriting your code would have pushed it over the brink -- unless the rewrite also modified array sizes or even changed all the 64-bit reals to 128-bits.  I'd suggest you replace `forall` with `do concurrent`, if your compiler implements it already.  It's a Fortran 2008 feature which is sometimes called `forall done right`.  I'm not saying it will sort the problem, it's more in the nature of an experiment on your code.

Comment: Wondering out loud: did you change the definition of `double` from `8` to `16` in your recent rewrite, in the pursuit of greater numerical precision ?  If you did you will have slowed your code a lot as your platform implements 128-bit floating-point arithmetic in software, it's not provided by the hardware.  Is it ?

Comment: agentp: I just called it "DOUBLE" temporararily for lack of a better name, I had no idea of a name at the time, thanks for the tip. This square_error function is very complicated.

Comment: HP Mark: yes I did increase the precision. Will try lowering it again, my hardware indeed does not support it.

Comment: francescalus: I was before using values of order 50e3, now I barely get to use 3e3. Sorry for the lack of the h, I am not a native English speaker, my code uses names in Portuguese, in fact, I just translated it quickly to post here.